# $expand and $count in odata v4

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am trying to expand child entity in entity but getting following error : 400 Bad Request

> Query option 'Expand' is not allowed. To allow it, set the 'AllowedQueryOptions' property on QueryableAttribute or QueryValidationSettings.

I set `[EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]`this property but no luck, then also fire same error.

Here is my URI :

```
localhost/OData/Ticket?$expand=Location
```

I also trying for get count of record but count also not working for me.Here is my URI for count.

```
 localhost/OData/Ticket?$count=true
```

But here also I getting 400 Bad request error with following message :

> The query parameter '$count' is not supported.

I did lot of google and found some related issues but that not work for me. Here is my Code:

- Controller :

  public class ODataTicketController : ODataController

  {

  ```
  [ODataRoute]

  [EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]

  public IQueryable<Ticket> Get()
  {
        return db.Tickets;
  }
  ```

  }
- Please help to resolve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally working all odata query on my controller. Just need IQueryable to IHttpActionResult. Now its working fine. Here is updated controller.

```
public class ODataTicketController : ODataController
{      
   [EnableQuery]       
   public IHttpActionResult<Ticket> Get()
   {
      var result = db.Tickets;      
      return Ok(result);
  }
}
```

Hope it will help someone.

Thank you.